Force in thermodynamic configuration space
Consider a thermodynamic system whose internal energy $U$ may not be conserved in general. It's a direct consequence of the First Principle that the variations in internal energy do not depend on the path followed in configuration space, just on the end and start points. Therefore, I was wondering whether it would be of any interest to define a Force $\vec F=-\vec \nabla U$ such that: $\oint\vec F\cdot d\vec l=0$. That is to say, in a completely analogous manner in which we define, for instance, the gravitational force.
Nonetheless, since the configuration space of a system is generally given by the triplet $(P,V,T)$, one would define the gradient as follows: $\vec \nabla \equiv \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial P}, \frac{\partial}{\partial V}, \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\right)$. Alternatively, we could also choose the representation $(S,V,N)$. For the latter, the force resulting from applying this gradient on the internal energy $U=U(S,V,N)$ would be: $\vec F=-(T,-P,\mu)$, since: $dU=TdS-PdV+\mu dN$
I feel like this dynamic analogy would allow us to define concepts such as thermodynamic equilibrium in a more intuitive way, since it would be completely analogous to equilibrium in Newtonian Mechanics (i.e: thermodynamic equilibrium is met if and only if $\vec F_A=\vec F_B$ for two systems in thermal, mechanical and chemical contact $A$ and $B$).
Additionaly, this approach would not pose any difficulties when it comes to the math, since the configuration space is a differentiable manifold.

IIRC there is a small section in Callen and in Pippard discussing the fact that classical mechanics is very different from all other physics theories in the specific behaviour that imbalances of "forces" in other theories tend to cause velocities, whereas in mechanics alone, forces causes accelerations. Thus, your equilibrium analogy has to be rather nuanced and it might just confuse people more than illuminate.  On an unrelated note, if you want to introduce gradients, it does not have to go by the name "force". Also, entropic forces are already defined and so you should not reuse that name.

I disagree with the "close" comments; Lagrangiano is not promoting "private" ideas, he is just asking. Anyhow, in the manyfold varieties of so-called "irreversible thermodynamics" all kinds forces are introduced. These usually start with either the Gibbs or the Gibbs-Duhem equation and assuming steady state in which the spatial gradient of the intensive quantity is the force acting on the temporal derivative of the conjugate extensive that is the flux. This has an enormous literature associated with the names of Prigogine, Glansdorff, and my favorite Bronsted, and many, many others.

I've voted to reopen because I think the expertise is present to discuss the idea fruitfully; it's not clear to me that it's outside the realm of mainstream physics.

I'm voting to close because there is no question here. Just the pondering of an idea. If the question is "whether it would be of any interest" that is still rather unclear and subjective. Since when is fruitful discussion a reason to reopen? This isn't a discussion site.

@BioPhysicist I disagree. This question looks reasonable to me.

@VincentThacker What question?

@BioPhysicist my question is about whether a conceptual reformulation of classical Thermodynamics can be made in order for it to resemble more other classical theories such as Mechanics. The interest I see in this approach is to explore the possibility of extrapolating results from Mechanics to Thermodynamics, since configuration space in Thermodynamics is very similar to configuration space in Hamiltonian Mechanics
